# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function put_to_cart_event(prodtitle, price, clicked_cell){
    var td = clicked_cell;
    alert(td);
    put_to_cart_({title: prodtitle, price: price}, function () {
        td.style.backgroundColor = '#859de6'; // <--- problem
    });
}
```

the alert is giving `[object Object]`, meaning the the `clicked_cell` is available and accessable, right?

what am I missing here?

the function is being called like this:

```
$('.abindenwarenkorb').on('click', function(){
    var productname = $('#productname').text();
    var price = $('#price').text();
    var in_stock = $('#in_stock').text();
    var clicked_cell = $('#clicked_cell').val(); //value is set like $('#clicked_cell').val($(this));
    put_to_cart_event(productname, price, clicked_cell); // <-- call
});
```

Comment: Need to see how your function is being called!

Comment: use `console.log(clicked_cell)` and see what is the object.

Comment: `$('#clicked_cell').val()` obviously isn't an element that would have `.style` applied to it.

Comment: issue is in this line `var clicked_cell = $('#clicked_cell').val();`  'val()' will return the value of the element , so instead of that set the use `var clicked_cell = $('#clicked_cell');`

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because `clicked_cell` doesn't have the style property. Could you output clicked_cell variable in console.log?

Comment: @doniyor you would need to invoke that `put_to_cart_event` by passing `$('#clicked_cell')` element to it as a parameter (`put_to_cart_event(productname, price, $('#clicked_cell'));`)and then in `put_to_cart_event` function, you should use something like `clicked_cell.css('background-color', '#859de6');` to change the background color.

Comment: @doniyor I can see why it wouldnt work even with this for you. Why dont you add a unique id to each one of those cells? and make it so that you pass that cell with specific id to put_to_cart_event?

Comment: thanks, it is hard to add unique id, because there 100s of such clickable elements. but I think, I have found a solution. huge thanks for your help :)

Comment: Np. I think it still make sense if you have unique ids, even if there 100s of clickable elements. Ids are supposed to be unique in a valid html. Good that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the element not the value 
change the below line

```
var clicked_cell = $('#clicked_cell');
```

see the below code :

```
$('.abindenwarenkorb').on('click', function(){
    var productname = $('#productname').text();
    var price = $('#price').text();
    var in_stock = $('#in_stock').text();
    var clicked_cell = $('#clicked_cell');
    put_to_cart_event(productname, price, clicked_cell); // <-- call
});
```

EDIT : 
In further reading through you code , i noticed this comment.

```
//value is set like $('#clicked_cell').val($(this));
```

this code is invalid `$('#clicked_cell').val($(this))` you cannot set an object as value. only serializable values are permitted. 
Other wise it will be converted to string , in your case it `[object Object]`

Comment: I think I got your problem here , you cannot set value as object.. @doniyor please see my updated answer.